# How to remember devices using AWS Amplify SDK?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have implemented a sign up/ sign in feature using AWS Amplify and swift using my own View controllers instead of the Drop-in auth. The problem starts once I quit the app and restart it. After I do that the user is no longer signed in. I have set remember devices to always in the User Pool Settings. [image: image of settings] Has anyone ever encountered this problem?
Here is my function where the user gets confirmed and everything works properly except for remembering the user

```
    @objc func confirm(){
        print("confirm pressed")
        guard let verificationCode = verificationTextField.text else{
            return
        }
        AWSMobileClient.default().confirmSignUp(username: username, confirmationCode: verificationCode) { (signUpResult, error) in

            if let signUpResult = signUpResult{
                switch(signUpResult.signUpConfirmationState){
                case .confirmed:
                    AWSMobileClient.default().deviceOperations.updateStatus(remembered: true) { (result, error) in //This is where I try to save the users device
                        print("User is signed up and confirmed")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let signedInTabBar = SignedInTabBarController()
                            self.view.window!.rootViewController = signedInTabBar
                        }
                    }
                case .unconfirmed:
                    print("User is not confirmed and needs verification via \(signUpResult.codeDeliveryDetails!.deliveryMedium) sent at \(signUpResult.codeDeliveryDetails!.destination!)")
                case.unknown:
                    print("Unexpected case")
                }
            }else if let error = error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Device remembering functionality does not work if you use one of the web UI sign in methods. [link](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/device_features/q/platform/js/#terminology)

Answer (score 1):

As I right understand you need to check if a user signed in or not. To do this you need to add this code on the start of the app or wherever you check a user status:

```
AWSMobileClient.default().initialize { userState, error in
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        if let error = error {
             AWSMobileClient.default().signOut()
            assertionFailure("Logic after init error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        guard let userState = userState else {
             AWSMobileClient.default().signOut()
             return
        }

        guard userState == .signedIn else {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After implementing this code caused my to discover another error on my part. Whenever I Sign in I print this func  `print(AWSMobileClient.default().isSignedIn)`  and it returns false even though I have signed in.